# "this" keyword does not refer to global object in my javascript program

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, this, arrow-functions

I implemented this code by using javascript to check how `this` works in arrow function.

```js
variable = 'Global variable';

function normalFunc () {
  console.log(this.variable);
}

const arrowFunc = () => {
  console.log(this.variable);
};

const objNormal = {
  variable: 'Inner variable',
  func: normalFunc
};

const objArrow = {
  variable: 'Inner variable',
  func: arrowFunc
};

objNormal.func();
objArrow.func();

arrowFunc();
```

I learned that `this` refers to global object in arrow function, so i expected the output like this

```bash
Inner variable
Global variable
Global variable
```

BUT the actual output was this...

```bash
Inner variable
undefined
undefined
```

Actually, it's really strange because this depends on where to run this code... in JS Fiddle, `this` refer to global object as i expected. But in my terminal and [this playground site](https://playcode.io/930958), `this` does not refer to global object.

Am i misunderstanding about `this` or just something is missing in my code?

Please help me to understand why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website linked [transpiles](https://devopedia.org/transpiler) the JS code to be inside a function, so `this` is not `window`. If you change your first line to be

```js
this.variable = 'Global variable';
```

the code works as expected.

When this is pasted into a `.js` file (`filename.js`) and ran with `node` (`node filename.js`), the `this` keyword is an empty object while `global` is a completely different thing. This is different from running this code in the REPL mode, where `this === global`.

In both cases, when you just say `variable = 'Global variable';`, you're assigning to `window.variable` or `global.variable`, so you can't access it with `this.variable`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! This helps me a lot!

I run this code in REPL, this is really interesting…

i learned that i should never use ‘this’ in arrow function. Thank you again!

Comment: It's not that you should never use `this` in an arrow function, it has its uses. The only thing you didn't know was that in some environments, the entry point's `this` is not `window`/`global`, and that variable assignments without a variable of the same name declared in-scope with `var`/`let`/`const` will always assign to `window`/`global`. An arrow function keeping the `this` context of wherever it was defined can be useful, so don't just dismiss it as something "i should never use" because then you're just limiting yourself

Comment: I'll keep it in mind! Thank you so much for your advice